# Standard for "CONTRIBUTORS"-style file (format, name, etc?)

Tags: contributor, documentation

In trying to deal with a codebase that was originally proprietary and then open sourced, new contributors are coming along.  Each file has names on it (though usually the main author's).

At this point, the codebase is drifting considerably.  Maintaining a list of names in each file seems to clutter it, and introduces an unnecessary awkwardness of "when a change is significant enough to be on the list".  There's also an issue of accuracy, because the name is generally not the person to try and contact about issues.

I was thinking that it would be best to just strike the names entirely, rely on the git blame log, and switch to a CONTRIBUTORS file.  *(This is along with a general push to take stuff repeated in each file and move it out to coding guidelines documents, etc.)*

This project is on GitHub and is:

- mostly C code
- has a `README.md` as its entry point for describing the project (80-column limited)
- has a `LICENSE` in text file format (Apache2)

So what sort of model might one use for a contributors file?  An all-caps CONTRIBUTORS seems like a long name.  Wondering what people call it and what would go in it.

---

It hit me right after asking that CREDITS.md would be a good short name *(somewhat obvious, and I've even used it in the past I believe)*.  But I wasn't acknowledging individual contributors to the code when I did this before, I was acknowledging the sources drawn from (libraries, tools, etc.) to build it.

So it still strikes me that these might be different files.  But maybe they could both go in one?  Then CONTRIBUTORS would be a section heading in the CREDITS.md file.

Comment: I personally dislike text THAT YELLS AT ME. I also personally think that this issue is so small compared to anything else, that it doesn't matter much. YMMV.

Comment: @Martijn If a question doesn't matter, why would one comment on it?

Comment: because you're asking it regardless, so either you've considered whether it's worth going further in to, and decided it is, or haven't given it any consideration. If it's the second, the comment would let you think about it. If it's the first, you can freely ignore it, it's only a comment.

Comment: @HostileFork Since you're using the Apache 2 license, have you considered making a NOTICE file with the information in it? A list of contributors may be a good fit for that.

Comment: Maybe "awkward" but necessary to record whose contribution is copyright by the contributor and whose is not.

Comment: I believe the practice of capitalizing these file names, e.g. README, COPYING, etc., comes from a Unix file system convention. Traditionally the directory sort of Unix systems listed capitalized file names first, so the file README would appear before any other file names that started with a lowercase letter. I believe the convention surives today because it gets your attention in a listing with several names. The one(s) which is (are) in all caps gets your attention visually, even if the directory is no longer sorted in the traditional Unix way anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using `.md` file, I take it that people won't be looking at the raw stuff with all the stars and what not. People will look mostly at the way that the file is "marked down". This means that you can use headers, and emphasis just like you note.

There isn't really a "standard" of doing this: Most projects create their own policies and standards to deal with varying situations in all aspects of project management, including contributions.

If you do create a `Credits.md` file, it would make perfect sense to include your contributors, as well as your sources. The markdown format will allow easier readability, and hence organizations between sources and contributors.

Separate files don't tend to be an issue either: If you feel that one file becomes too large and thus virtually overshadows other critical sections of files, then it becomes easier also to split them up.

If you have an avid list of contributors, and you are recording each contribution they make to various files, then it would make perfect sense to keep them in separate files, just like I mentioned above.

Comment: Well, it's not the [Debian credits list](https://www.debian.org/devel/people), so I guess one file will do!  CREDITS.md, start with the individual contributors in one section, then libraries and tools used below.

Answer (score 7):

There is no *standard* way of listing contributors, but there are some *conventions* and habits.

The [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler has a `MAINTAINERS` file (in its source tarball) which could inspire you

Comment: AUTHORS is another one I think I remember seeing, somewhere.  I think I might go with CREDITS, and put the people most involved up top and then go on to the libraries, because the people contributing directly are likely to be more miffed if not at the top of the file.  :-/

Answer (score 5):

Apparently theres this standard/specification/bot:

https://allcontributors.org/

Here is more info:

https://allcontributors.org/docs/en/overview

And here is a big example:

https://github.com/all-contributors/all-contributors#contributors-

Comment: That's a handy proposal, especially for large projects, but I don't think it's widely adopted enough that it qualifies as a _standard_.

Answer (score 1):

Humans.txt is a good candidate. It was made for websites but it could be used anywhere since it’s basically a list of contacts.
https://humanstxt.org/

Comment: At the moment, I think that suffers from the same problem that David Z identifies with allcontributors,org, above: it is by no means sufficiently widely adopted to constitute a standard.

Comment: True. The conclusion might be that there is no widely agreed upon format, so we just have to start somewhere and push one of these (and certainly not create a new format) *insert xkcd standards here* lol

Comment: Or alternatively, accept that there's no widely-accepted standard, stop looking for one, and just do something reasonably sensible.  I think that's basically Zizouz212's accepted answer, above.